# Ruby on rails templates for apps (rails 2.3 version)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, automation

Is there any site or repository to download and/or share templates for Rails applications?

Example:

```
# template.rb
run "rm public/index.html"
generate(:scaffold, "person name:string")
route "map.root :controller => 'people'"
rake("db:migrate")

git :init
git :add => "."
git :commit => "-a -m 'Initial commit'"
```

And do that:

```
rails myapp -m ~/template.rb
```

... or that:

```
rails myapp
cd myapp
rake rails:template LOCATION=~/template.rb
```

Comment: This link helps: http://m.onkey.org/2008/12/4/rails-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using authlogic and declarative_authorization in my Rails apps, so I thought I could meet the basic settings used in application templates, and/or search for such templates somewhere.

I didn't find repositories of templates, only found an automatic template generator. So I created a template according to my needs, and published in http://gist.github.com/b66c262ee2e8b27d416f.